# Alchemy C Code compilation

Tags: c, alchemy

I am using alchemy to compile the C code.

This is the way I am compiling

```
gcc oggvorbis.c -O3 -Wall -swc
oggvorbis.swc -lvorbis
```

I am getting an error

```
llvm-gcc: oggvorbis.swc: No such file
or directory.
```

But the command works fine when i don't use any shared library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line invocation should probably read (untested)

```
gcc oggvorbis.c -O3 -Wall -swc -o oggvorbis.swc -lvorbis
```

Comment: @above: still it's not using the -lvorbis.